# Reallocate Storage in Red Hat 6

Tags: redhat, lvm, rhel6

Is it possible to (safely) reallocate storage space in /home to the root filesystem?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_root   50G   35G   13G  74% /
tmpfs                          24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                     485M   64M  396M  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home  478G  235M  453G   1% /home
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way? Shrink the /home partition and expand /. That's how I had to do it (RHEL 6.4 has that as the default setup). Most of the instructions are located here: http://www.tcpdump.com/kb/os/linux/lvm-resizing-guide/all-pages.html

Here's the overview:

Unmount: `umount /home`
Resize: `lvresize -L -400GB  /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home`

Apply: `resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home`

Then do it again for root:

`lvresize -L +400GB  /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_root

resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_root`

Then finally remount it: `mount /home` - or, if for some reason this doesn't work, `mount /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home /home`

After, run `fsck` on both just to be safe. You can do this with the mounts active, although I highly recommend ending any running processes if possible. Also, it goes without saying but I *highly* recommend you have a good backup as anything can happen.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it.  But are you sure you can shrink mounted volumes?  `man resize2fs` certainly claims otherwise.

Comment: You're right, but LVM partitions are treated slightly differently in that shrinking does work when online (since they're not "real" partitions but logical).

Comment: do I need to make any changes in fstab to make sure these changes remain after reboot?

Comment: Nope.  The partition/volume sizes are written to disk as they're run.

Comment: I get this error:
`Filesystem at /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home is mounted on /home; on-line resizing required
On-line shrinking from 127047680 to 22190080 not supported.` when I run `resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home`

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected apparently. Some kernels don't support online shrinking. Use `umount /home` first then mount it again after resizing.

Comment: @NathanC Would you edit your answer to reflect the umount /home and whatever I would need to do to remount it

Comment: All done. Should have done that before.

Comment: One other thing I was going to bring up, didn't, but really probably should have.  I believe the `resize2fs` should be done before the `lvresize`.  That way, there is a period where the filesystem is smaller than the volume.  The reverse is significantly more of an issue.  As evidenced by http://serverfault.com/questions/517336/unexpected-inconsitency-run-fsck-manually-redhat/517352#517352

Comment: @ChristopherKarel The `lvresize` has to be done first as `resize2fs` will then read the volume data that `lvresize` wrote and do what it says. If you run `resize2fs` it'll simply say there's nothing to do.

Comment: You can specify a size to `resize2fs`.  I would assume that clears up the 'nothing to do' problem.  http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs  That being said, I believe resize2fs should only be run first on the shrinking portion.  Your order is correct for the growing part.

Comment: @ChristopherKarel That works on physical partitions (like sda1 and such) but not LVMs.

Comment: Fair enough.  I clearly don't work with those much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the file system resize in the same step with the inclusion of `-r`.

```
umount /home
lvreduce -rL -100G /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_home
lvextend -rL +10G /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_root
```

I'm also going to suggest that at this time you create additional filesystems for your log directories (/var/log, and /var/log/audit), at a minimum. A rogue service can start vomiting all over your filesystem. You want to segregate your logs so this doesn't impact operations. (You really don't want root to fill up..)

```
lvcreate -n log -L8G vg_yavin
mkfs.ext3 -L log /dev/mapper/vg_yavin-lv_log
```

Then, create your `/etc/fstab` entry and `mount -a`.

Also, leave a few gigs unallocated so you can grow something in a pinch without having to unmount something else.